# What does 唐乐乐 mean?

Tags: vocabulary, phrase

In the context of  "唐乐乐睁开眼睛，看着头上陌生的天花板。" What would be the meaning of the phrase "唐乐乐"? While I understand the rest of the sentence perfectly, this bit makes no sense to me. 
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the name of the person who opens her/his eyes to stare at the unfamiliar ceiling above.

唐: family name

乐乐: given names